# Как при нажатии на "," (запятую) не выводить её в input? (chips component React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook

Я создаю chips компонент. Вот мой codesandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-glitter-dkh25?file=/src/App.js для примера. Я набираю текст в input и при нажатии на запятую (",") создаю новый чипс. Однако после создания этого чипса у меня в input остается запятая.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я хотел бы что-бы она не появлялась. Как мне это сделать?

Функция добавления чипса

```
  const handleKeyDown = (event) => {
    if (event.key === ",") {
      setChips([...chips, event.target.value]);
      setInput("");
    }
  };
```

Comment: При нажатии на запятую? Это кнопка с текстом "," или при вводе через клавиатуру? И какая логика заключены при этом? Где функция, которая создает чипс (?). И каким образом вообще можно добавить в текст запятую? А если их не должно быть, то в чем проблема удалить их?

Comment: При нажатии на кнопку клавиатуры (запятая-это где русская б). Реализовал пример в codesandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-glitter-dkh25?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Добавьте сюда код функции, обрабатывающей нажатие запятой.

Comment: Добавил в верху

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не зная логики работы ваших функций можно предложить классику - `event.preventDefault()`.

```js
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('keydown', event => {
  if (event.key === ",") {
    console.log(',');
    event.preventDefault();
  }
})
```

```html
<input type="text">
```